# Publish Django Project on Windows Server

Tags: django, web-deployment, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I have a home server(OS: WindowsServer 2016 STD) with ip static and i want publish my Django project on a windows server from my home server.
What should i do to other people can access my project using my ip static!?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it as development server then you can simply do: 
`python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0` and then access it using your IP address.

Else you can follow [this link](https://www.toptal.com/django/installing-django-on-iis-a-step-by-step-tutorial) to deploy Django on your Windows IIS server for production.

Comment: I have read this instruction and deploy my project on windows IIS but i don't know how to use my ip static to other people can access my project from their pc

Comment: Ideally just using your static IP address instead of localhost URL in your browser should be able to get anyone to acess your page, is that what you are asking?